# R issue : performing lm and then a boxcox to find a proper lambda value

Tags: r, indexing, lm

I have a dataset of climate data in a data.frame (columns are measuring stations, and rows indicate time of measurement), and I'm trying to find the proper lambda values in a Yeo-Johnson transform to limit skewness impact on a principal component analysis.

Obviously, the first step is to get log likelihoods to find the best lambda : I use the following, where i is the index of a column :

```
getYeoJohsnonLambda <- function(myClimateData,cols,lambda_min, lambda_max,eps)
...
lambda <- seq(lambda_min,lambda_max,eps)
for(i in cols)
    {
    formula <- as.formula(paste("myClimateData$",colnames(myClimateData)[i],"~1"))
    currentModel <- lm(formula,myClimateData)
    print(currentModel)
    myboxCox <- boxCox(currentModel, lambda = lambda ,family="yjPower", plotit = FALSE)
    ...
    }
```

When I am trying to call it for a climateData time series which could be, for example :

```
`climateData <-data.frame(c(8.2,6.83,5.46,4.1,3.73,3.36,3,3,3,3,3.7),c(0,0.66,1.33,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1.6))`
```

I get this error : `Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'myClimateData' not found`

This is weird, as lm seems to find it and return a correct fit, and myClimateData should be found as it is one of the arguments of the function, right ?

Comment: The issue is with the way you form your formula: `formula <- as.formula(paste("myClimateData$",colnames(myClimateData)[i],"~1"))`. Instead, try something like `lm(as.formula(paste(colnames(climateData)[1], "~1")), data=myClimateData)`

Comment: I tried changing to :

  `currentModel <- lm(as.formula(paste(colnames(myClimateData)[i], "~1")), data=myClimateData)

  print(currentModel)
  
myboxCox <- boxCox(currentModel, lambda = lambda ,family="yjPower", plotit = FALSE)`

But I still have the same error : " Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'myClimateData' not found" in the BoxCox line.

This is really weird as "myClimateData" is one of the function args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, it seems that the problem comes from the function boxCox rather than your `getYeoJohsnonLambda` function. As [BrodieG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487646/r-data-table-with-box-cox-transform-from-mass-package) pointed out [in a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487646/r-data-table-with-box-cox-transform-from-mass-package), this function uses `parent.frame` as an argument to `eval` which is considered as bad practice in the doc.

One way to solve this is to build the models before the call, as suggested in [Adam Quek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6203226/adam-quek)'s answer:

```
library(car)

climateData <- data.frame(c(8.2,6.83,5.46,4.1,3.73,3.36,3,3,3,3,3.7),c(0,0.66,1.33,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,1.6))
names(climateData) <- c("a","b")

modelList <- list()
for(k in 1:ncol(climateData)) {
  modelList[[k]] <- lm(as.formula(paste0(names(climateData)[k],"~1")),data=climateData)
}

getYeoJohnsonLambda <- function(myClimateData, cols, lambda_min, lambda_max, eps)
{
  #Recommended values for lambda_min = -0.5 and lambda_max = 2.0, eps = 0.1
  myboxCox <- list()
  lmd <- seq(lambda_min,lambda_max,eps)
  for(i in cols)
  {
    cat("Creating model for column # ",i,"\n") 
    currentModel <- modelList[[i]]
    myboxCox[[i]] <- boxCox(currentModel, lambda = lmd ,family="yjPower", plotit = FALSE)
    
  }
  return(myboxCox)
}

test <- getYeoJohnsonLambda(climateData,c(1,2) ,-0.5,2,0.1)
```

Other solution (arguably cleaner): use `yeo.johnson` in `VGAM`

```
library(VGAM)

getYeoJohnsonLambda_VGAM <- function(myClimateData, cols, lambda_min, lambda_max, eps)
{
  #Recommended values for lambda_min = -0.5 and lambda_max = 2.0, eps = 0.1
  myboxCox <- list()
  lmd <- seq(lambda_min,lambda_max,eps)
  return(apply(climateData,2,yeo.johnson,lambda=lmd))
}

test2 <- getYeoJohnsonLambda_VGAM(climateData,c(1,2) ,-0.5,2,0.1)
```

Comment: I feel really stupid Antoine, as it turns out the car package already has a "powerTransform" function that does exactly what I want. Sorry for the inconvenience...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without troubleshooting the function `getYeoJohsnonLambda`:

```
iris.dat <- iris[-5]
vars <- names(iris.dat)
lmd <- seq(.1, 1, .1) #lambda_min, lambda_max, eps

all.form <- lapply(vars, function(x) as.formula(paste0(x, "~ 1")))
all.lm <- lapply(all.form, lm, data=iris.dat)

library(MASS)
all.bcox <- lapply(all.form, boxcox, data=iris.dat, 
            lambda=lmd, family="yjPower", plotit=FALSE)
```

Comment: As it seems, this yields "Error in boxcox.default(X[[i]], ...) : response variable must be positive
In addition: Warning message:
In lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
 extra argument ‘family’ will be disregarded "

Indeed : my variables have zero values (it's why I use Yeo-Johnson instead of Box-Cox).

Comment: A more detailed look at stack trace suggests it is an issue with "eval(expr, envir, enclos)", pointing to the kind of issues encountered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22617354/object-not-found-error-within-a-user-defined-function-eval-function ... I tried using "noquote" as they do, but to no avail.